# How to take backup of users created in openam and reuse them in another instance?

Tags: openam

is it possible to take a backup of all the users created in openam, so that I could use the backup to configure a new instance of openam. I am using the embedded datasource for the storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to:

- [OpenDJ Administration Guide - Chapter 4. Importing and Exporting
  LDIF
  Data](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/chap-import-export)
- [OpenDJ Administration Guide - Chapter 9. Backing Up and Restoring
  Data](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/3/admin-guide/chap-backup-restore)

By default, OpenAM creates user data under ou=people,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org in OpenDJ if using embedded OpenDJ as user data store.